# planning to use Jaeger for distributed tracing

Tags: distributed, jaeger

Planning to use Jaeger for distributed tracing of our Application.
Need to use elasticsearch as db backend, rather than cassandra for Jaeger.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic search works fine for this. And Kibana allows you to build nice aggregated views of the traffic.

A recommendation from my experience is to use the `--es.tags-as-fields.dot-replacement` option and specify a character. This flattens the data structure. Its very useful because ElasticSearch/Kibana struggle with the tags data as an array.